# How to access Facebook methods in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, android-asynctask

What i need to do to get the userId, facebook profile pic, emailid and address of currently logged In user.

Once app authorize an user logged-in i'll call below method in Async Task but it fails and throwing exception:-

"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Please have a look over method that i execute in doInBackground() of asynctask:-

```
private void callFBMethods() {

    try {
        response = facebook.request("/me");
        if(response!=null)
        {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
        mainURL = Constant.FB_PIC_URL+json.getString("id")+"/picture?type=small";
        //To registere new user here
        Vector<Object> userData = new Vector<Object>();
        userData.add(Constant.CURRENT_FLAG);

        userData.add(json.getString("username"));
        userData.add(json.getString("name"));
        userData.add(json.getString("id"));
        userData.add(mainURL);

        new AsynServices(mActivity, userData, 4).execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("exception occurs:-"+e.getMessage());
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` this error because of From Android API 14 onward you have to run internet related code should be in AsyncTask. Like this you can run your code in AsyncTask

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

      // call your methods from here

      try {
         response = facebook.request("/me");
         if(response!=null)
         {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
         }
         JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
         mainURL = Constant.FB_PIC_URL+json.getString("id")+"/picture?type=small";
         //To registere new user here
         Vector<Object> userData = new Vector<Object>();
         userData.add(Constant.CURRENT_FLAG);

         userData.add(json.getString("username"));
         userData.add(json.getString("name"));
         userData.add(json.getString("id"));
         userData.add(mainURL);

         // instead of calling another Asynctask here just write related code here.

         new AsynServices(mActivity, userData, 4).execute();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
         System.out.println("exception occurs:-"+e.getMessage());
     } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i did the same but its not working, see the code what i am running in doInBackground method. Thanks.

Comment: yes, i did the same as you wrote here but this is working in my samsung based on Froyo but not working in HTC based on Jelly bean.